# Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 8

Tags: android, sqlite

im trying to retrive whole data from databse in android...

---

**Sqlite Query:-**

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM stud",null);
```

---

**But Exceptions:-**

```
07-04 18:47:26.249: E/CursorWindow(8314): Bad request for field slot 0,-1. numRows = 1, numColumns = 8
07-04 18:47:26.259: D/AndroidRuntime(8314): Shutting down VM
07-04 18:47:26.259: W/dalvikvm(8314): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.my.StudentInfoManagement/com.my.StudentInfoManagement.ListData}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString_native(Native Method)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:329)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:49)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at com.my.StudentInfoManagement.DataHelper.selectAll(DataHelper.java:52)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at com.my.StudentInfoManagement.ListData.onCreate(ListData.java:18)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
07-04 18:47:26.329: E/AndroidRuntime(8314):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118409/androidjava-lang-illegalstateexception-get-field-slot-from-row-0-col-1-failed  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4703634/illegalstateexception-get-field-slot-from-row-0-col-1-failed

Comment: @kalpana , please can you share your code ( Actually my program controller is not getting inside getChildCursor() method .

Answer (score 0):

Ha-ha after 2 days work , in this case , today my senior ( Vijar Sir ) suggest me to convert `id` (primary_Key) name into : `_id` & its runs successfully ,

Now if you say why After implementing phone_contact : [here](http://www.vogella.com/code/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList2.html) than hover above **Contacts._ID** , you will find `_id` string associated with it .

```
private static final String[] CONTACTS_PROJECTION = new String[] 
{
     Contacts._ID,
     Contacts.DISPLAY_
};
```